# Background image in fullscreen

Tags: css, image, fullscreen

I use this code to show image full screen in my desktop

```
<style>
 body{
  background: url("under-constraction1.jpg")no-repeat fixed 0 0 / cover ;
 }
</style>
```

but in mobile in Firefox browser a piece of my image is shown

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
 body{     
    background: url("under-constraction1.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
 }
```

Comment: it is ok on the desktop but in firefox mobile browser all of my image is not shown

Comment: Hi, Is it work on other mobile browser like chrome than Firefox mobile browser?

Comment: may be version problem check https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-size  or check https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("./images/under-constraction1.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```